# foreign keys with "ON DELETE CASCADE"

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys

Does anybody know how to add foreign keys with "ON DELETE CASCADE" for table of type "InnoDB"

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)?

Comment: I've executed this query "ALTER TABLE tbl_businessalbum ADD CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY ( businessId ) REFERENCES tbl_business ( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE" for MyISAM. The query is executed successfully bt MyISAM engine doesn't deal with Foreign keys DELETE CASCADE property http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD FOREIGN KEY xyzkey (field1, field2, ...) REFERENCES foreigntable (foreignfield1, foreignfield2, ...)`. This is something you could've googled in under a microsecond. And MyISAM tables do NOT support foreign keys at all. Any foreign key directives are ignored/dropped. You must use InnoDB tables for foreign keys.

Comment: @anamus php You ask about InnoDB, but in your comment you say you tried it with MyISAM.  It's unsupported in MyISAM, but will work fine as you have it for InnoDB

Comment: ALTER TABLE tbl_businessalbum
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (businessId) REFERENCES tbl_business (id) ON DELETE CASCADE I'm using this bt its showing me this error #1005 - Can't create table 'mydb.#sql-9ec_f0' (errno: 150)

Comment: this means that id and budinessId are not of the same type... or maybe one (or both) of the tables is not InnoDB?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that both tables are InnoDB. Even if create statement indicates InnoDB, if this engine is not installed, MySQL will use MyISAM instead. So check if they are actually InnoDB.

Next, make sure both columns are exactly the same type (for example if one of them is int(11) and the other one is int(11) unsigned, you can't create a foreign key). Make sure that the column you are referencing (id in the bussiness table in your case) have unique index (MySQL will allow to use any indexed column, but it's best to use unique index). If it's the primary key, it already has unique index.

Next, run the statement, according to the documentation and as pointed by other users:

`ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD FOREIGN KEY xyzkey (field) REFERENCES foreigntable (foreignfield) ON DELETE CASCADE;`

If you can't add foreign key, you can [create trigger instead](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)